# Preserving quotes in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm using `ruamel.yaml` for modifying a YAML file. My requirement is to add a value for an existing key, preserving everything else including the order. I got it to work, but looks like quotation marks of other keys/values get modified too in the process.

1. For some cases, double quotes get converted to single quotes. E.g.

   **Before**

   ```
   node_js:
     - "0.10"
   ```

   **After**

   ```
   node_js:
     - '0.10'
   ```
2. In some other cases, quotes get dropped altogether. E.g.:

   **Before**

   ```
   before_script:
     - "cp test/config-x.js src/config.js"
   ```

   **After**

   ```
   before_script:
    - cp test/config-x.js src/config.js
   ```

Both of these cases appear in the same file. How can I stop this from happening and preserve the quotes as it is in the original?

I use `load_yaml_guess_indent()` for loading and `round_trip_dump()` for writing it back.

Comment: I somehow overlooked that you are using `load_yaml_guess_indent()`, you can specify `preserve_quotes=True` for that function as well, that argument will be passed on to the `round_trip_load()` function

Comment: Thanks. I got that figured. It'll be nice to have a reference to all the options that are supported, like this.

Comment: Sorry to be slow, but `data, ind, bsi = load_yaml_guess_indent(open(file_name),preserve_quotes=True)` gets me a `TypeError: YAML.load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'preserve_quotes'` error. am i missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default ruamel.yaml "normalizes" things like indentation and removes any superfluous quotes. It also defaults to the single quotes on output, when those are necessary as those indicate simpler strings (i.e. only single quotes have special meaning and these are a better/simpler option to distinguish strings that could be interpreted as numbers than double quotes are).

What you probably missed is that you **explicitly have to tell the** `round_trip_loader()` **to preserve quotes**, using the `preserve_quotes=True` argument:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str_1 = """\
node_js:
  - "0.10"
"""

yaml_str_2 = """\
before_script:
  - "cp test/config-x.js src/config.js"
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml_str_1)
ruamel.yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('=====')
data = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml_str_2)
ruamel.yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
node_js:
- "0.10"
=====
before_script:
- "cp test/config-x.js src/config.js"
```

With that option all strings are loaded in special subclasses of strings that are then output as they were loaded. These classes need to be used if you replace such a loaded value, as just assigning a new value will not preserve the type. Adding:

```
data['before_script'][0] = type(data['before_script'][0])('ln -s xxx /usr/local/bin')
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
before_script:
- "ln -s xxx /usr/local/bin"
```

(that type happens to be `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString()`)

Answer (score 18):

`yaml.preserve_quotes = True` works in the current version of `ruamel.yaml`.